# Dropdown menu of Vertical menu not working properly with margin

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, web, vs-web-site-project

Hi experts brother/sister,

I'm working with a website and have faced a problem with drop down menu. There are two drop down menus at the website. One is horizontal drop down menu and another is vertical drop down menu. I've put two drop down menu successfully.
Kindly see the images of that at first:

1. Drop down menu of Horizontal Menu (Parent "Shopping cart")
   [image: Drop down menu of Horizontal Menu]
2. Drop down menu of Vertical Menu (Parent "Magazine")
   [image: Drop down menu of Vertical Menu]

I've faced problem with second one(Drop down menu of Vertical Menu):
The drop down menu belongs to "Magazine" tab. You may see that there are a margin between the main navigation/tab and drop down navigation. My problem is for that margin. I've to use that margin. But, **for creating that margin I can't put mouse on the drop down menu easily from "Magazine nav"**.

You can check the [link](http://abidhasan.zxq.net/help/).
Look, there are also a margin from "Shopping cart" menu to it's drop down menus(image 1). But, it can be easily put mouse on that drop down menu from "Shopping cart". But, you can't select/put mouse easily at the drop down menu of "Magazine" menu.

Though there are also a margin from "Shopping cart" menu to it's drop down menu, it haven't created problem. Because, I've given a height to "Shopping cart" li which seem margin in open eye. So, there are no actual margin(marin-top) from "Shopping cart" menu to it's drop down menu. But, I can't use the same technique for "Magazine" menu I mean I can't use more big width for "Magazine" menu to take as a abstract margin for its drop down menu. Because, there are background colors and image at the "Magazine" menu which takes place too if I use more big width instead of margin.

So, can you please help me? Can I make clear to you about my problem? In short, I like to tell you that **I can't put mouse easily form "Magazine" menu to it's drop down menu because of creating a margin at left side from "Magazine" menu to it's drop down menu**.

Thanks to all for reading my problem.

(I've tried to give my code for that menus at here. But, I couldn't format here. That's why, I've uploaded it if anybody need: [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2auoux3a0jvm2i/help.zip))

Comment: No doubt at all you should grow your right margin and keep content controled. You could work with left-col and its contents UL & LI in order to keep on hovering. It seems that 20 pixels of margi-right will do

Comment: I don't understand your solution clearly. Yes, there are about 15px margin from "Magazine" menu to it's drop down menu. I've already gotten an easy solution from Andy Allcorn. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an awful hack, but you could fake the margin like this:

```
.vertical_nav li ul li {
  border-left: 15px solid #fff;
}
```